# Pylint or another linter which can handle functools.partial

Tags: python, static-analysis, pylint

Are there any linters available which can keep track of uses of `functools.partial` in order to (partially) check for argument correctness? I only really care whether this is done for the initial call to partial, and possibly within the same scope. For example I'd like the following to raise errors:

```
def f(a):
    pass

partial(f, 1, 2) # too many arguments
partial(f, b=3) # non-existent keyword argument
g = partial(f, 1)
g(2) # too many arguments (this one would be nice, but not necessary)
```

Comment: I think mypy + typehints would catch this if you're willing to add add type annotations to your code

Comment: @dustinroepsch alas I am not

Comment: http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/how_tos/custom_checkers.html
You could probably write a custom checker for catching the arity mismatch. You might b able to get the named parameter check working as well. I don't think you'd be able to catch the third class of error you listed though.

Comment: @dustinroepsch Ah that looks great, I'll take a look.